# How to use select result with like in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I need some MySQL code that uses a select output in LIKE statement in WHERE.

I mean something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id,parent_id FROM units WHERE ptitle 
like '%(SELECT ptitle FROM units WHERE id='".$id."')%')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT id FROM (

SELECT id,parent_id FROM units WHERE ptitle

like concat('%',(SELECT ptitle FROM units WHERE id='".$id."'), '%')

) sub_table
```

Comment: thanks Haim,i used your code and it got me an error.but it worked well when i change the positon of concat and put it inside the inner select,in this form: LIKE (SELECT CONCAT('%',ptitle,'%') FROM units WHERE id=...)